IPC Endpoint closes immediately after it opens GETH
I am attempting to establish communication between a bootstrap and member node on the same device using GETH on Windows. Initialising both nodes with my genesis.json file works fine.
geth --datadir bootstrap --networkid 3129 --port 30305 --ipcpath geth-bootstrap.ipc --nat extip:192.168.1.104

I find the node record of bootstrap
geth attach --exec admin.nodeInfo.enr \\.\pipe\geth-bootstrap.ipc

I attempt to connect the member node and recieve this output
geth --datadir member0 --networkid 3129 --ipcpath \\.\pipe\geth-member0.ipc --port 30307 --bootnodes enr:-KO4QOqxRCdkc_NUSC_QzvCPSQa86Qiv_7NL-kbH76YSSr5FR7bX-cIiBI3IFTtmqIHWDRUqVbSM2S_wW7hsLB7UP72GAY9TS9gZg2V0aMfGhIDbYXKAgmlkgnY0gmlwhMCoAWiJc2VjcDI1NmsxoQLBIm4wbRxu_DswTxRkKG8nlTxCq-DBT1sD5BoR-kTjMoRzbmFwwIN0Y3CCdmGDdWRwgnZh

INFO [05-07|15:06:06.267] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.13.14-stable-2bd6bd01/windows-amd64/go1.21.6
INFO [05-07|15:06:06.287] New local node record                    seq=1,715,089,572,444 id=89707b6b3336ef4c ip=127.0.0.1 udp=30307 tcp=30307
INFO [05-07|15:06:06.287] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://8a4a29f6b5a069226f47ce96cba07d007b5ec8941505b972316371e1e44ccdc836e83dc8d11e2b51f33f51deb8aef2f9507e87a0fe2778ddd3c9a0fcfcb860ea@127.0.0.1:30307
INFO [05-07|15:06:06.291] IPC endpoint opened                      url=\\.\pipe\geth-member0.ipc
INFO [05-07|15:06:06.291] Loaded JWT secret file                   path="C:\Users\M\Documents\Geth\member0\geth\jwtsecret" crc32=0xc52b610a
INFO [05-07|15:06:06.307] IPC endpoint closed                      url=\\.\pipe\geth-member0.ipc
INFO [05-07|15:06:41.301] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=9 static=0

Peer count = 1 is giving me a reason to believe a connection is made, but it's not through IPC. I wish to attach member0 but can't do that when its IPC endpoint closes.
